# UnorderedMap returns Out of Bounds error when inserting in NEAR

Tags: nearprotocol

I'm currently having an issue with inserting a key-value pair in NEAR Protocol for Unorderedmap.

Here's my pseudocode:

```
let mut new_list: UnorderedMap<String, Struct> = UnorderedMap::new(b"m");
// iterate through old list
for (key, data) in old_list.iter() {
    let new_data_to_push = Struct {
        data: old_data.data,
    };

    new_list.insert(&key, &new_data_to_push);
}
```

I'm migrating data from an old list to a new list with new data for a migrate function.

I can't seem to figure out why there is an Out of Bounds error for an UnorderedMap.

Answer (score 1):

We discovered that if you migrate an UnorderedMap, it should contain a totally new name and not the same name again and again. Hence, Index Out of Bounds issue will occur because it accesses the same Map due to the same name.